# Alternative function for android_createDisplaySurface?

Tags: c, opengl-es-2.0, android-9.0-pie

We are working on android9 to run opengl simple triangle .c application, if we remove the function `android_createDisplaySurface()` in the program we are getting bus error. if we add that function we will get undefined reference error. is there any alternative function to call `displayWindow` or else any file to be added.

error line is

```
egldisplay = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
displayWindow = android_createDisplaySurface(g_FrameBufferID);
```

Comment: Have you tried to actually resolve the undefined reference? Why are you looking for alternative functions for which chances are you will bump into the same problem anyway? Find what resolves the undefined reference and link against it.

Comment: For undefined reference we have to call or create ANativewindow but we didn't get any resources for ANativewindow, how to use and call the ANativewindow. if you know any reference other than www.developers.android.com please let me know